# Selection.SpecialCells() method returns unexpected range (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

When I select a range of three cells say B3:B5, the method acts as expected and displays three messages with "3", "4" and "5".

```
Sub visTest()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        MsgBox c.row
    Next c
End Sub
```

The problem is when I select only one cell:
the `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` returns ALL visible cells on the worksheet and starts from the cell A1.

How do I make it return only one visible cell within the one selected cell?
Why the problem occurs?

Thanks!

Comment: you could verify the interval of the selection, and if there's only one cell, use the `xlCellTypeLastCell` on the for each loop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will perform the correct restriction:

```
Sub visTest()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Intersect(Selection, Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
        MsgBox c.Row
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it returns all used cells on the worksheet is that SpecialCells method, as many other methods in Excel, assumes you want the [used range of the worksheet](http://codevba.com/excel/worksheet_usedrange.htm) if your specified range only contains a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

to eliminate the problem with incorrect range when using "specialCells" just put this line to the code

`If Selection.Cells.Count > 1 Then  Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
End If`

This way excell will use this method only when actually sellected region consists of more than one cell.