# in Excel VBA why does my code not work with SpecialCells type visible and work without it?

Tags: excel, vba

In columns Bk and CB they both contain formula's that will result in a code. Now CB will also contain four codes and a remove statement which if they match with the cell in column BK in the same row then take the value from CB and paste over hence overriding the value in BK with that code and then paste it red.

the above should be done only on a filtered range though.

The ignore #N/A are in there as the overide column will error out on almost everyline except for when there is a code to overide.

This macro works perfectly without the visible cells statement at the end of my with range line but as soon as the visible cells statement is added the loop only goes up to #N/A and disregards the rest of the ElseIF statement.

Here is my code below:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Override()

Dim x As Workbook: Set x = ThisWorkbook
Dim rRange As Variant, fltrdRng As Range, aCell As Range, rngToCopy As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Dim LR2 As Long
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Dim mRow


mRow = 2

Set ws = x.Worksheets("Data")
LR = ws.Range("CB" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LR2 = ws.Range("BK" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'clears any filters on the sheet
ws.AutoFilterMode = False

' turns formula's to manual
Application.Calculation = xlManual

'copies down the formula in Column BK ignoring the last two rows as they have already been pasted over.
ws.Range("BK2:BK4 ").AutoFill Destination:=ws.Range("BK2:BK" & LR2 - 2)

'filters on N/A's and 10 as these are the codes we are interested in overiding

ws.Range("$A$1:$CB$1").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:=Array( _
        "10", "N/A"), Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues



' will loop through all cells in specified range and ignore any error's and #N/A's and will paste over the code overided in CB column to the BK column if conditions are met.
On Error Resume Next

While IsEmpty(ws.Range("CB" & mRow)) = False
    
    With ws.Range("CB" & mRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    If .Value = "#N/A" Then
    ElseIf .Value = "1234" Then
        .Offset(0, -17).Value = "1234"
        .Offset(0, -17).Interior.Color = vbRed
    ElseIf .Value = "1235" Then
        .Offset(0, -17).Value = "1235"
        .Offset(0, -17).Interior.Color = vbRed
    ElseIf .Value = "1236" Then
        .Offset(0, -17).Value = "1236"
        .Offset(0, -17).Interior.Color = vbRed
    ElseIf .Value = "Remove" Then
        .Offset(0, -17).Value = "Remove"
        .Offset(0, -17).Interior.Color = vbRed
    ElseIf .Value = "1237" Then
        .Offset(0, -17).Value = "1237"
        .Offset(0, -17).Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
    End With
    
mRow = mRow + 1

Wend
            
            
'turn Formula 's back to automatic
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
            
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove that `On Error Resume Next` and report back on which line is throwing the error and what the error message is.

Comment: I've tried that before and it gives me a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch just after the #N/a condition. So the if #N/a line is highlighted yellow in the debugger.

Comment: `If .Value = "#N/A" Then` doesn't work to check if the cell's value is an error. Use `IsError` or `Application.IsNA` - see the linked duplicate.

Comment: The code works when I don't apply the visible cell rule and loops through while disregarding the "#N/A"s, the issue when I apply the visible cell the macro still works as in there is no error break in the code it just doesn't loop through the rest of the conditions and just keeps looping up to "#N/A" but still loops through the whole cell range.

Comment: As I mentioned, `If .Value = "#N/A" Then` is quite problematic and needs fixed.

Comment: Also using `SpecialCells` on just one cell is [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832388/selection-specialcells-method-returns-unexpected-range-excel-vba).

Comment: I've replaced If .Value = "#N/A" Then with  If IsError(.Value) Then and carries out my first Elseif condition on the #N/A cells, not sure if I'm using it correctly. The SpecialCells is supposed to be just on CB Column range unless that's where my code is messing up. (Not sure how to code format the code in my replies sorry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `With ws.Range("CB" & mRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)`

Using `SpecialCells` on just one cell is [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832388/selection-specialcells-method-returns-unexpected-range-excel-vba).

Instead, use it on the entire filtered column, like this, which will replace your entire `While...Wend` loop (by the way, `While...Wend` is obsolete):

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim visibleCells As Range
Set visibleCells = ws.Range("CB2:CB" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0

If visibleCells Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In visibleCells
    If Not IsError(cell.Value) Then
        Select Case cell.Value
            Case "1234", "1235", "1236", "1237", "Remove"
                cell.Offset(0, -17).Value = cell.Value
                cell.Offset(0, -17).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End Select
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so far and your continued patience. I've replaced my code with your new one and it seem's I get the error 13 Type mismatch on the Case line. Would we need to do a string transformation?

Comment: Do any of the visible cells contain an error value?

Comment: Yes, they will contain #N/A which is to be expected and skipped past.